# How to get sum of array elements between two zeros

Tags: java, arrays, sum

first input: size of array: 5

second input: 0 -2 4 0 6

output: 2

Here is what I have tried. It is also adding the numbers before zero:

My code's output:

array size: 10

elements: 6 19 0 -3 4 8 0 -6 9 59

my output: 25 9

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n]; 
        Vector<Integer> A = new Vector<Integer>();

    int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
 
   
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
       if (arr[i] == 0)
       {
           i++;
           break;
       }
    }
 
   
    for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        
    
       if (arr[i] == 0)
       {
           A.add(sum);
           sum = 0;
       }
        
       else
       {
           sum += arr[i];
       }
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < A.size(); j++)
    {
       System.out.print(A.get(j) + " ");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 2 loops, one to look for the first zero and then sum up.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[n];
        List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<>();
        int sum = 0;

        // read input
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        boolean isCounting = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] != 0 && isCounting) {
                sum += arr[i];
            } else if(arr[i] == 0){
                // if already counting then finish the sum
                if (isCounting) {
                    sums.add(sum);
                    sum = 0;
                } else { // else start counting
                    isCounting = true;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sums);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = in.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        int sum = 0;
        int idx = 0;
        while (arr[idx] != 0)
            idx++; // After this, idx will be the index of the first 0
        do {
            idx++; // Keep looping from idx + 1 until the next 0
            if (arr[idx] != 0 && idx < arr.length)
                sum += arr[idx];
        } while (idx < arr.length && arr[idx] != 0);
        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int sum = -1;
> int j = -1;
>     
>     for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++ ){
>        if (arr[i] == 0) {
>            j = i;
>            if (sum == -1)
>                sum = 0;
>             else
>                break;
>        } 
>        if ( j == -1)
>           continue;
>         sum += arr[i];
>     }
> ```

The above should work

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    int sum = 0;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        if (arr[i] == 0) {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }

    for (int i = list.get(0); i <= list.get(list.size()-1); i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```